# jq group_by does not play nice with .[]

Tags: json, terminal, jq

I have a json file locally called `pokemini.json`. These are the contents of it;

```
{"name":"Bulbasaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":318,"hp":45,"attack":49}
{"name":"Ivysaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":405,"hp":60,"attack":62}
{"name":"Venusaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":525,"hp":80,"attack":82}
{"name":"VenusaurMega Venusaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":625,"hp":80,"attack":100}
{"name":"Charmander","type":["Fire"],"total":309,"hp":39,"attack":52}
{"name":"Charmeleon","type":["Fire"],"total":405,"hp":58,"attack":64}
{"name":"Charizard","type":["Fire","Flying"],"total":534,"hp":78,"attack":84}
{"name":"CharizardMega Charizard X","type":["Fire","Dragon"],"total":634,"hp":78,"attack":130}
{"name":"CharizardMega Charizard Y","type":["Fire","Flying"],"total":634,"hp":78,"attack":104}
{"name":"Squirtle","type":["Water"],"total":314,"hp":44,"attack":48}
```

There are a few types of pokemon in here and I want to do some aggregation with `jq`.

I could, per example, write this command;

```
> jq -s -c 'group_by(.type[0]) | .[]' pokemini.json
[{"name":"Charmander","type":["Fire"],"total":309,"hp":39,"attack":52},{"name":"Charmeleon","type":["Fire"],"total":405,"hp":58,"attack":64},{"name":"Charizard","type":["Fire","Flying"],"total":534,"hp":78,"attack":84},{"name":"CharizardMega Charizard X","type":["Fire","Dragon"],"total":634,"hp":78,"attack":130},{"name":"CharizardMega Charizard Y","type":["Fire","Flying"],"total":634,"hp":78,"attack":104}]
[{"name":"Bulbasaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":318,"hp":45,"attack":49},{"name":"Ivysaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":405,"hp":60,"attack":62},{"name":"Venusaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":525,"hp":80,"attack":82},{"name":"VenusaurMega Venusaur","type":["Grass","Poison"],"total":625,"hp":80,"attack":100}]
[{"name":"Squirtle","type":["Water"],"total":314,"hp":44,"attack":48}]
```

I am aware that the `-c` flag is what is causing it to print line by line and that I need `-s` to handle the fact that my json file is more like jsonlines that actualy json. It should also be pointed that out there are only three types of pokemon detected because I can grouping over `.type[0]` (note that `[0]`).

I don't get why this does not work though;

```
> jq -s '.[] | group_by(.type[0])' pokemini.json
jq: error (at pokemini.json:10): Cannot index string with string "type"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by/1` expects its input to be an array. By calling .[] first, you are effectively undoing the work of the -s option.

By the way, an alternative to using -s is to use `inputs` with the -n command-line option, but in this case it makes little difference. When you don’t actually need to read all the entire stream of inputs at once, though, using `inputs` is in general more efficient.